# Adjust assertions for maven tests

Tags: java, maven, junit

I working on a Java/Maven project. I use `mvn test` to run my test suite. However, in this case all assertions are enabled. Unfortunately this increase the time of some operation from `log(n)` to `n^2` which is rather inconvenient. What is more is that the operation is defined in a dependency `packageA` whereas I work on `packageB`. Using plain Java I could add `-ea:packageB...` to enable only the assertions which I actually need. Is it possible to achieve this behaviour using either the content of the `pom.xml` or a command line argument to `mvn`? I know I can disable *all* assertions but I would rather keep the assertions in the package that I am actually working on...

Comment: If refactoring your code is possible, you could try to use something [similar as explained here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20857658/dynamic-method-dispatch/20857998#20857998) where your have your basic asserts in the base class and all of the asserts to omit in certain cases in a dispatched object. Via maven profiles you could decide then if you want all of the assertions or just the basic ones. In general, you should separate your unit-tests into [categories](http://www.hascode.com/2012/12/running-categorized-tests-using-junit-maven-and-annotated-test-suites/) though

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using surefire-plugin. But first you need to specify profiles for different packages.

Using surefire-plugin you can exclude or include packages, using wildcard or regex.

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.18.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <includes>
        <include>%regex[.*[Cat|Dog].*Test.*]</include>
      </includes>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

---

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.18.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <excludes>
        <exclude>**/TestCircle.java</exclude>
        <exclude>**/TestSquare.java</exclude>
      </excludes>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

You can find more detailed information [on this site](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html).

Comment: Well, I don't want to include / exclude testcases, I would like to enable / disable `assert` statements...

Comment: @hfhc2 What is the difference? Why would you want to still execute test but without asserts? What you expect to gain from that? Instead just exclude packages you do not want to run.

Comment: Well, I still want the `assertTrue` / `assertEquals`... statements to be tested...

Answer (score 0):

I use these properties:

```
<maven.test.skip>false</maven.test.skip>
<maven.test.failure.ignore>false</maven.test.failure.ignore>
```

Then you can leave the Asserts as is, but change these properties to either fail on Assert.fail(), or don't do the tests at all.

Or similarly an extra parameter using CMD, like adding:

> -Dmaven.test.skip=true